# When I come back from other screens to ViewPager, then ViewPager is totally Blank, What could be the cause?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

This my ViewPagerAdapter where I am setting all my three fragments tabs
This my ViewPagerAdapter where I am setting all my three fragments tabs
if anyone there is to help me out.
if anyone there is to help me out.
if anyone there is to help me out.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    String tabTitles[] = new String[] {"BELUM TERKIRIM", "TERKIRIM", "DIBATALKAN"};
    Context context;
    BelumTerkirim belumTerkiri = null;
    Terkirim terkirim = null;
    Dibatalkan dibatalkan = null;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, Context context) {
      super(manager);
      this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return tabTitles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      switch (position) {
        case 0:
          if(null == belumTerkirim)
            belumTerkirim = new BelumTerkirim();
          return belumTerkirim;
        case 1:
          if(null == terkirim)
            terkirim = new Terkirim();
          return terkirim;
        case 2:
          if(null == dibatalkan)
            dibatalkan = new Dibatalkan();
          return dibatalkan;
      }
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
      return tabTitles[position];
    }

    public View getTabView(int position) {
      View tab = LayoutInflater.from(PesananActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
      TextView textView = (TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.custom_text);
      textView.setText(tabTitles[position]);
      return tab;
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is how I am setting the adapter

Comment: ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

Comment: does the viewpager already is in a fragment if so you will need to use childfragmentmanager.
can you write how do you use this adapter (from the activity/fragment)?
you can edit you main post and add your code there

Comment: @visionixvisionix I am using from activity and I am calling three fragments on single viewPager.

Comment: viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
      TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
      tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
    }

Comment: try to set viewpager adapter from onResume

Comment: @visionixvisionix thanks it's working for me now ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrong thing was I wasn't creating new instances of each fragment when we back from any other page then we always must create instances of fragment.Below code worked for me.

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      switch (position) {
        case 0: 
          return new BelumTerkirim();
        case 1:
          return new Terkirim();
        case 2:
          return new Dibatalkan();
        default:
        break;
      }
      return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY this

```
ViewPager viewpager=null;
```

then under your method

```
viewpager =(ViewPager)findviewbyid(R.id.pager);
FragmentManager fragmentmanager=getSupportFragmentManager();
viewpager.setAdapter(new Myadapter(fragmentmanager);
```

try this and let me know